# Suma de valores distintos SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join

¿Cómo puedo hacer una suma de los valores distintitos que obtengo de una consulta?

Mi consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT distinct d.Id_Venta, b.Cantidad, d.Clave_vendedora
  FROM [dbo].[TB_AbonoMicro] A join [dbo].[TB_AbonosMicroDetalles] b on a.IdAbono = b.IdAbono
  join [dbo].[TB_EsquemaPagosMicros] c on a.Fecha = c.FechaPagado join [dbo].[TB_Ventas] d on c.Id_Venta = d.Id_Venta
  where a.fecha > '20220126' 
  and d.Clave_vendedora = 1
```

y obtengo el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo que quiero obtener es en la cantidad el valor de: 272

Comment: Así: `SELECT SUM(b.Cantidad) FROM [dbo].[TB_AbonoMicro] A join [dbo].[TB_AbonosMicroDetalles] b on a.IdAbono = b.IdAbono join [dbo].[TB_EsquemaPagosMicros] c on a.Fecha = c.FechaPagado join [dbo].[TB_Ventas] d on c.Id_Venta = d.Id_Venta where a.fecha > '20220126' and d.Clave_vendedora = 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De manera rápida puedes hacer una subquery, para que sumes los importes, con la palabra SUM(campo), quedando así tu consulta:

```
SELECT SUM(Datos.Cantidad) FROM 
(
    SELECT distinct d.Id_Venta, b.Cantidad, d.Clave_vendedora
    FROM [dbo].[TB_AbonoMicro] A join [dbo].[TB_AbonosMicroDetalles] b on a.IdAbono = b.IdAbono
    join [dbo].[TB_EsquemaPagosMicros] c on a.Fecha = c.FechaPagado join [dbo].[TB_Ventas] d on c.Id_Venta = d.Id_Venta
    where a.fecha > '20220126' and d.Clave_vendedora = 1
) AS Datos
```